# how to map a value from an object array into the style of a render element

Tags: react-native

i have an object array like this. [{message:"text 1", likecolor:"blue"},{message:"text 2", likecolor:"yellow"}]. i am able to iterate the value of "message" into my Text element. However i cant assign the value of likecolor to the color of my icon. In my code below it doesnt make any changes to the color of the icon. Here is my code

```
/**
  this is my object array 
  [{message:"text 1", likecolor:"blue"},{message:"text 2",likecolor:"yellow"}]
*/

 this.state.messagestable.map((count) => {
     return (
              <Card transparent key={count.message_id}>
                  <Text>{count.message}</Text>
                  <Icon name ="ios-heart" style={{color:count.likecolor}} /> 
              </Card>
             )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add your color just by doing

```
<Icon color={count.likecolor}/>
```

UPDATE.

i created a snack that works, the code is like yours, see if you find some differences: https://snack.expo.io/SJ1EQQ8bH

Comment: What <Icon/> component are you using? If it's standard vector-icons than there's no style prop you can use

Comment: import { Icon } from from 'native-base'. i assume its the icons from ionicons.

Comment: the initial code u gave didnt work unfortunately. It doesnt support the color props. The color can only be defined in the styles property as style={{color :'colorname' }}

Comment: I checked the docs from native-base and your solution should work, are you sure the colors are passing?

Comment: here is an example from the docs https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#icon-def-headref  `<Icon ios='ios-menu' android="md-menu" style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'red'}}/>`

Comment: the code from snack worked in my project. Im going to use that as a guide to fix my  problem. Thanks for the help

Comment: the example from snack worked finally after restarting the server